# Suppressing form resubmission dialog

Tags: javascript, forms, browser, post

Is there a way (using javascript or other means) to suppress the form resubmission dialog that pops up when a page containing post data is refreshed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem and the solution has a name: [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

The page that receives the *POST* handles it and then *redirects* the client/browser to another page which is retrieved with a *GET* request. So if the client refreshes, they are not re-POSTing the data.

Comment: Can I take it then that I can't have a page that shows the dialog sometimes (eg when users presses f5), but not other times (eg when javascript calls window.location.reload() )?

Comment: `window.location.reload()` will attempt to re-post if the page is a POST request. You could try `window.location = window.location.href`

Comment: The trouble is I need the re-post to happen (if I use location = location.href post data is lost), but don't want the user to be prompted if it's happening because of a refresh they didn't directly request. Specifically, it happens when they login using a form in a lightbox midway through completing a questionnaire, and after the login the page is refreshed in order to update the navigation to the logged-in state.

Comment: Are you saving the questionnaires state in hidden fields? Can you store it in a Session instead and use PRG?

Answer (score 2):

The popup shows before the content is loaded. So any Javascript will be executed after you clicked one of the buttons on the popup.

What you can do on the server side is redirecting to another page (with no POST data) after completing all your actions with the data.